# How to pass dynamic Options base on page number in pdfkit

Tags: python-3.x, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I am generating pdf from html string using pdfkit and wkhtmltopdf in python. Everything is working fine. But I need to specify different page marging for first page and rest of the pages. Is there any options to do this? Below is my code.

```
html = template.BuildHTML().buildhtml(data)
headerHtml = HeaderTemplate.BuildHTML().buildhtml(data)
footerHtml = FooterTemplate.BuildHTML().buildhtml(data)
options = {
            'page-size': 'A4',
            'orientation': 'Portrait',
            'dpi': '600',
            'margin-top': '50',
            'margin-right': '10',
            'margin-bottom': '40',
            'margin-left': '20',
            '--encoding': 'utf-8',
            '--header-spacing': '2',
            '--footer-spacing': '5'
         }
add_pdf_header(options, headerHtml)
add_pdf_footer(options, footerHtml)
pdfkit.from_string(html, PdfFilePath, options=options)
```